# Powerful tools for creating SQL queries

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a tool, which would help creating complex SQL queries. Sometimes it's difficult to even verify, whether the results of a query are correct. It's especially easy to get queries joining several tables to return too little or too much data.

The tool should enable at least creation of test tables, some kind of visualization how the queries gather their data and hopefully give better parsing of error cases than for example Oracle does.

Are there tools like this or do I have to stick with creating test tables manually, filling them with test data and commiting all kinds of queries with SQuirrel SQL?

Answer (score 2):

When you have a very complex query it is usually easiest to validate by breaking it up into multiple queries that populate temp tables. These intermediary results can be individually verified and then you bring them together to produce the final result set. Depending on performance needs you can stick with the temp table approach or you can then rewrite to a single statement. Typically when I have a huge query it is for background processing so I stick with the temp table approach.

Answer (score 1):

What RDBMS are you using? All of the major ones have some type of console available (e.g.-SSMS in SQL Server, Toad in Oracle, MySQL Query Browser/Administrator for MySQL, etc.), and they all have Query Execution Plans where you can see how the query will actually run.  So, the answer to your question is that it's entirely dependent on what RDBMS you're using, but the safe bet answer is: Yes.

Comment: I'm using Oracle currently. I'm aware of explain plan, but it gives pretty low level information.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express (SSMSE) if you are working with SQL Server. I have used it at work and I believe it does everything you are looking for.

You can get it and SQL Server (express editions) [here.](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Even though I'm using Oracle I wouldn't mind creating the most complex queries using a different DB.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not a free, open-source solution, but I believe Quest Software's TOAD will fit your requirements.  Quest seems to offer alot of tools in that space...they have tools for modeling and analysis, however I've never used the modeler or analyzer.

I personally have experience with the commercial version of TOAD for Oracle.  It's GUI is overwhelming at first, but after you mentally filter out all of the extra buttons that you'll never use, it's manageable.